# Copy & paste artwork with editable text from Adobe Illustrator to InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, copy-and-paste, editorial-design

I can't believe it: when pasting some diagram drawing with text from Illustrator to InDesign, text is not completely editable and becomes broken.

I would like to adjust text in InDesign brochure composing, or edit it before finalizing later.

What's the options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copy/paste, save the Illustrator file and place it in the InDesign document. Every change made at the original file will be reflected in the InDesign document updating the link at the **Link Panel**:

[image: Link Panel]